# Angular 7 - Multiple Dropdowns Selection Change

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a form array, the array consists of formGroup with `brand` and `model`.

**Component:**

```
get brands() {
  return this.form.get('groups') as FormArray;
}

addGroup() {
  this.groups.push(
    this.fb.group({
      brand: ['', Validators.required],
      model: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  );
}

removeGroup(index: number) {
  this.models.removeAt(index);
}

brandSelect(event: any) {
  // I dispatch an action to get the models from the smart component
  this.selectedBrand.emit(event);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ng-container formArrayName="groups" *ngIf="groups">
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="addGroup()">
      <small>
        <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-fw margin-xs-r"></i> Add Group
      </small>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div *ngFor="let control of groups.controls; index as i">
    <div class="text-right margin-sm-b">
      <a (click)="removeGroup(i)"> <i class="fas fa-times fa-fw"></i> </a>
    </div>

    <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Brand</mat-label>
        <!--Based on the brand selected I dispatch an action to get the models.-->
        <mat-select
          formControlName="brand"
          (selectionChange)="brandSelect($event)"
        >
          <mat-option *ngFor="let brand of brands" [value]="brand">
            {{ brand | titlecase }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Model</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="model">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let model of models" [value]="model">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-fw margin-xs-r"></i> {{ model }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

`brand` and `model` is a dropdown. I show the list of models based on the brand selected, I dispatch an action on brand `selectionChange` to get the list of models.

As the model is an Observable which I've subscribed to. Everything works fine when I have only one item in the form array. The moment I add another group, on brand `selectionChange` the `model` observable gets updated with the latest data and the `model` in the first `group` goes blank because a different brand was selected from the second group.

How can I handle this situation while I'm using NGRX?

Comment: I think you're going to have to show more code to get some help.

Comment: @JeffryHouser, pls do let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unknown User, you need severals "models". For this, you can make that models was an object.

The idea is that,e.g., models was

```
models={
   "seat":["ibiza","leon","panda"],
   "kia":["cerato","ceed"]
}
```

And you iterate over models[brand]

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let model of models[brand]" [value]="model">
   <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-fw margin-xs-r"></i> {{ model }}
</mat-option>
```

So, define at first your models as

```
models:any={}
```

And, when change the brand fill

```
models[brand]=....an array of the list of models of this brand
```

Comment: So I literally have to store the models for each brand in the form array, right? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: NOT. models is an object (each property is an array), but NOT belong to your form, belong to your component

Comment: Yea, that's what I meant. I'm gonna follow this answer to solve this thing now.